# Panning with right click in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I've been using JOSM a lot lately and have grown accustomed to panning the map with a right click (ie. right click, hold and drag) while having a left click activate the selected tool. I'm wondering if it is possible to configure this behaviour in QGIS. I think I've looked through most of the various configurations options and haven't been able to find an option for this. It seems at present that a right click doesn't do anything when the cursor is over the map.

Comment: Middle click does this in Qgis, not sure if you can reconfigure it.

Comment: I've tried the middle click too to no effect. Perhaps I've reconfigured something at some point without realizing it? I tried middle clicking with both a mouse wheel and my laptop's built in middle key.